Android DOMException: Could not start video source. (No active stream)
I browsed other question like this, but couldn't find any working solutions.
When I want to access a videodevice I get a DOMException error and in other questions the answers were to stop the previous stream, but I already do.
In my angular project before calling the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia I stop the last stream like this:
 private async stopCurrentStream(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      this.video.nativeElement.pause();
      this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = null;
      this.video.nativeElement.src = null;

      if (!this.stream) resolve();

      this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
        track.stop();
        this.stream.removeTrack(track);
      });
      this.stream = null;
      resolve();
    });
  }

And this is how I want to start a video stream:
private async startVideo(
    deviceId: string = this.videoDevices[0]?.deviceId
  ): Promise<void> {
    console.log('start vid', deviceId);

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
         deviceId: {exact: deviceId}
        },
      })
      .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
        console.log('then', stream);
        this.stream = stream;
        this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.nativeElement.play();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error accessing the camera with id', err);
      });
  }

The strange thing I only get this error if I'd like to access a specific camera, if I remove the device id it always works. However I'd like to be able to switch between cameras.
Also if I loop the startVideo function until it succeeds, after 20-100 retries later it manages to access the camera. I tried setting a timeout between stopping and starting a video stream, but no success.

Test this behavior on webcamtests.com, if the behavior is reproduced, then you might be facing a hardware issue.

On webcamtests.com it loads my camera on the first try.
